# Bootstrap - Inline text spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got some error w/ bootstrap, it's about this:
When I create div class with form-group and put label in it so to the right of label is input form. It looks kinda this:
 [image]

But in text-text form is different, when I create same form with label to the left and simple text to the right there is spacing about few px and it looks like this:
[image]

Is there any errors in CSS or maybe I am using wrong div classes for only text?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the code aswell. The amount of soothsayers among us is limited..

Comment: Have you tried changing the `line-height` to ensure they match, this is likely caused due to the text on the left having a larger height property that the text on the right.

Comment: Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/ZNk9LkxT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `form-control-static` class should apply the proper padding for you:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">some label</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <p class="form-control-static">some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```